# Tabulator: Have a value associated with cell

Tags: tabulator

I am deciding to use this wonderful `Tabulator` js library but I want to have a different value associated with each cell value that is displayed.

Like

```
<td value="1">Bob</td>
```

I see the below options for setting a drop down

```
columns:[ 
        {title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"select", editorPramas: names
        ]
```

where `names = { 1: 'Bob', 2: 'Jack'}`

however this results in bob and Jack being displayed in the drop down and when `Bob` is selected it displays `1` in the cell value. However I want Jack and Bob to be in dropdown and when `Bob` is selected data cell gets value of `1` because I have columns values mapped to IDs which need to be stored in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by custom `editorParams`

```
columns:[ 
        {title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"select", editorPramas: myCustom
        ]

var myCustom = function(cell) {
    cell.getElement().setAttribute("value",2);
    ...
}
```

whereby one can get the cell element which is changed and accordingly change any attribute of it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this feature should be considered and generic in the next release.
I proposed a hack for the input editor but this should be done in a generic way with the new parameter elementProps

https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1869